# Save R output as an object

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

Suppose, I have fitted my data to a multivariate DCC model and do the forecasting to get mean returns. Below is my reproducible code.

```
# load libraries
library(rugarch)
library(rmgarch)
library(FinTS)
library(tseries)
library(fPortfolio)
data(dji30retw)

for (i in 1:2)
{ Dat.Initial = dji30retw[, 1:8, drop = FALSE]
  Dat <- Dat.Initial[1:(1000+(i-1)), ] 

#Fitting the data
uspec = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0)), variance.model = list(garchOrder = c(1,1), model = "sGARCH"), distribution.model = "norm")
spec1 = dccspec(uspec = multispec( replicate(8, uspec)), dccOrder = c(1,1), distribution = "mvnorm")
fit1 <- list()
fit1[[i]] = dccfit(spec1, data = Dat, out.sample = 120, fit.control = list(eval.se=T))

#Out of sample forecasting
dcc.focast <- list()
dcc.focast[[i]]=dccforecast(fit1[[i]], n.ahead = 1, n.roll = 0)
#print(dcc.focast[[i]])

#Mean returns 
mean.focast <- list()
mean.focast[[i]] = fitted(dcc.focast[[i]] )
print(mean.focast[[i]])

#Var-Cov 
covmat.focast[[i]]= rcov(dcc.focast[[i]])
print(covmat.focast[[i]])
}
```

R has given me the output in this form:-

```
, , 2004-01-30

             AA         AXP         BA         BAC           C         CAT         CVX          DD
T+1 0.002903173 0.003462776 0.00295735 0.003485212 0.004442807 0.002986181 0.002069151 0.002367464

, , 2004-02-06

         AA         AXP         BA         BAC           C       CAT        CVX          DD
T+1 0.002933206 0.003511235 0.00300817 0.003510005 0.004436862 0.0029913 0.00205337 0.002382313
```

Is there any way we can save the output as one object/xts so it will look something like this?

```
               AA              AXP         ..........  DD
 30-01-2004    0.002903173   0.003462776   ........... 0.002367464
 06-02-2004    0.002933206   0.003511235   ........... 0.002382313
```

And another question, why is it if I type only 'mean.focast' , it gives me the following output?

```
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
, , 2004-02-06

             AA         AXP         BA         BAC           C       CAT        CVX          DD
T+1 0.002933206 0.003511235 0.00300817 0.003510005 0.004436862 0.0029913 0.00205337 0.002382313
```

Where is the value for [[1]]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see. Your "troubles" are from this part of the code

```
#Mean returns 
mean.focast <- list()
mean.focast[[i]] = fitted(dcc.focast[[i]] )
print(mean.focast[[i]])
```

You ask to print the output for each iteration (which is why you get the output you get), but note that you reinstantiate the list `mean.focast` in each step of the iteration. That is why you get `NULL` for the first list element, because you've made a new list and are only filling in element 2 (for iteration 2). The  `mean.focast <- list()` should be moved outside the loop.

As for the `mean.focast` result. You can combine the list elements into a single data frame in tons of ways. Here's one using `reshape2`.

```
library(reshape2)
res <- dcast(melt(mean.focast), Var3 ~ Var2)
res
        Var3          AA         AXP         BA         BAC           C
1 2004-01-30 0.002903173 0.003462776 0.00295735 0.003485212 0.004442807
2 2004-02-06 0.002933206 0.003511235 0.00300817 0.003510005 0.004436862
          CAT         CVX          DD
1 0.002986181 0.002069151 0.002367464
2 0.002991300 0.002053370 0.002382313
```

So your final code becomes

```
mean.focast <- list()

for (i in 1:2)
{ Dat.Initial = dji30retw[, 1:8, drop = FALSE]
  Dat <- Dat.Initial[1:(1000+(i-1)), ] 

#Fitting the data
uspec = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0)), variance.model = list(garchOrder = c(1,1), model = "sGARCH"), distribution.model = "norm")
spec1 = dccspec(uspec = multispec( replicate(8, uspec)), dccOrder = c(1,1), distribution = "mvnorm")
fit1 <- list()
fit1[[i]] = dccfit(spec1, data = Dat, out.sample = 120, fit.control = list(eval.se=T))

#Out of sample forecasting
dcc.focast <- list()
dcc.focast[[i]]=dccforecast(fit1[[i]], n.ahead = 1, n.roll = 0)
#print(dcc.focast[[i]])

#Mean returns 
mean.focast[[i]] = fitted(dcc.focast[[i]] )
print(mean.focast[[i]])}

res <- dcast(melt(mean.focast), Var3 ~ Var2)
res
```

Comment: What is the Var3 ~ Var2?

Comment: I have search that the second part in dcast is the formula. But I dont understand that why do we need to choose Var 3 ~ Var 2.

Comment: If you see from the question, I have added one last part in the loop, which is the `covmat.focast`. I have tried to combine the list elements into a single data frame using the code you have showed earlier, but it says "Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length". Can you help me please?

Comment: If you look at `melt(mean.focast)` you can see that some of the columns have names `Var2`, `Var3` etc.

Comment: Can you show another simple way to combine the `mean.focast` result other than using `dcast` function please?

Comment: Try `do.call("rbind", mean.focast)` and then you need to add column names and possibly the time